# Stock Footage of Alan Shepard in The Right Stuff?

Tags: realism, the-right-stuff

In The Right Stuff (1983) lots of stock footage is used. There's one scene in particular that I'm pretty sure uses stock footage. But I'd like a confirmation. It's the scene when Alan Shepard is about to board the capsule and NASA engineers are watching him and clapping. Shepard looks up at the capsule and gives a thumbs up sign. Then he takes the elevator up and boards the craft. This capture is an example of what I think is stock footage.

[image: The Right Stuff (1983), Stock Footage Sample 1]

[image: The Right Stuff (1983), Stock Footage Sample 2]

[image: The Right Stuff (1983), Stock Footage Sample 3]

The following is definitely not stock footage. It's a capture of the heavy handed character of the Minister, played by Royal Dano. The scene would have been much better served without these Dano inserts.

[image: The Right Stuff (1983), Royal Dano Sample 1]

[image: The Right Stuff (1983), Royal Dano Sample 2]

Comment: To answer my own question, yes those first three captures are indeed of Alan Shepard preparing to board Freedom 7. The footage can be seen here (2:45 to 3:45): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xd9kg-fJ9g

Comment: IMDb confirms what you're saying as correct.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, yes those first three captures are indeed of Alan Shepard preparing to board Freedom 7. The footage can be seen here (2:45 to 3:45): youtube.com/watch?v=3xd9kg-fJ9g –